# Почему не работает псевдоэлемент ::marker

Tags: css

Почему не работает псевдоэлемент ::marker ?

В документации описано как работает marker и приведен пример.
Но приведенный пример не работает, почему ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

```css
ul li::marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Peaches</li>
  <li>Apples</li>
  <li>Plums</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Браузер не поддерживает. Непопулярная эта фича (внизу документации есть список).

Comment: Может по этому - https://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Amarker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Она не работе в хроме. На сайт, который вы отметили все написано:

> From version 80: this feature is behind the Enable experimental Web
>   Platform features preference.

Если открыть сайт в Firefox, например, то все будет работать отлично:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Я даже не подумал что в Chrome что то может не работать :)
По мне - так нужная вещь